# How to put a while loop in a variable?

Tags: php

Well, it aren't more then the code actually!

```
$toq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users") 
or die(mysql_error());  
$to = while($row = mysql_fetch_array($toq)) { echo "".$row['mail'].", "; };
echo $to;
```

Comment: @Petah Not everyone is a native English speaker, you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to save all the entries in an array, like this:

```
$to = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($toq)) { 
    $to[] = $row['mail'];
}
```

Then, to echo is as a comma-separated string, use [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode):

```
echo implode( ', ', $to);
```

This is better than the alternative, which is to use string concatenation, but will inevitably add an extra comma to the end:

```
$to = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($toq)) { 
    $to  .= $row['mail'] . ',';
}
```

In order to remove that trailing comma, use [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/rtrim):

```
$to = rtrim( $to, ',');
```

Comment: @JoakimMelin - You're welcome! I'm my post answered your question, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Also, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: +1 for knowing what the heck...